# Objects overlapping on some computers

Tags: c++, opengl

I've an application using OpenGL to draw some content in a window (based on the example from [here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/apis-and-tools/creating-3d-tools-with-mfc-r1358)). Everything looks good when application running on my desktop PC with NVIDIA GeForce GTS 450 graphic card, but it looks terrible on other computers (I've tried on 2 notebooks with intgrated Intel graphic cards, and on the virtual machine running on VirtualBox).

The effect looks like this:

[image: incorrect effect]
[image]

I've tried to manipulate gluPerspective function but without results.

What may be the reason for such effect?

EDIT:
Correct files from computer with NVIDIA attached:
[image]

Comment: Are those the good looking or the bad looking pictures?

Comment: Bad looking of course...

Comment: I guessed so, but that's like guessing someone is pregnant... just don't do it. Anyway, you should post good looking ones of similar scenes, so that we can know what is exactly wrong with them.

Comment: Sure, I've added a screen with correctly displayed objects

Comment: It looks like some kind of [z-fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). It happened to me once: my program looked fine with 32-bit ZBuffer but horrible with a 16-bit one. If that is the case, you should reconsider all your Z coordinates.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint! I've read the link you post, and tried to change z-buffer depth in PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR passed to SetPixelFormat function. It looks like changing it to 32bit (from 16bit) solved my problem! Please post your comment as answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I't looks like some kind of [z-fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). That is you have several geometries with overlapping or very similar Z values, and precision errors in the calculations of the Z values make that some parts of your objects are hidden.

The fact that it works in some machines and not in others may be caused by the Z-buffer being 32-bits or 16-bits, depending on the machine.

Note that even if forcing your Z-buffer to 32-bits may solve the issue, you should consider fixing the Z-values of your objects. There are (used to be?) some hardware out there that doesn't support 32-bit Z-buffers.